# Error 126 module not found on very simple C windows api program

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I first had troubles creating a Window, as the window wouldn't show, then I checked for errors using `GetLastError()` function, and it printed error code 126 which means module not found according to MSDN (This usually appears when loading DLLs, but I don't do any of that).
I am using GCC compiler.
Help would be appreciated.

**This is the code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

WNDCLASSEXA myWindowsClass = {};

LRESULT myMainProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{    
    return 0;
}

void setDefaultClassParameters(HINSTANCE hInstance);

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    printf("ERROR CODE: %i\n", GetLastError()); // Prints 126 Error
    SetLastError((DWORD)0);
    printf("ERROR CODE: %i\n", GetLastError()); // Prints 0

    setDefaultClassParameters(hInstance);
    RegisterClassExA(&myWindowsClass);

    CreateWindowExA( 
        WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        "MY CLASS NAME",
        "MY WINDOW TITLE",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );
    printf("ERROR CODE: %i\n", GetLastError()); // Prints 126 Error
}

void setDefaultClassParameters(HINSTANCE hInstance){

    myWindowsClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    myWindowsClass.style = CS_OWNDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    myWindowsClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) myMainProc;
    myWindowsClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    myWindowsClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    myWindowsClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    myWindowsClass.hIcon = NULL;
    myWindowsClass.hCursor = NULL;
    myWindowsClass.hbrBackground = NULL;
    myWindowsClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    myWindowsClass.lpszClassName = "MY CLASS NAME";
    myWindowsClass.hIconSm = NULL;    
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything but print something. Don't check `GetLastError` unless your last operation actually failed.

Comment: I did that actually, I tried to set the Error with `SetLastError()` to 0 but then I used `RegisterClass()` function and it reset the error again to 126 implying that I have the problem some where in my program.
Edit: Also when I tried to create a window that failed too.

Comment: @KhalidAlHajri [edit] and show the code you're talking about. The code you show right now doesn't make sense. Read this: [ask] and read about this: [mcve]

Comment: We can't help you with code we can't see. If you don't show us the code you have problems with, how can you expect us to know what the problem might be?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I just edited the code to show where I actually had the error.

Comment: OK, now it is better. Your calls to `GetLastError` dont make any sense. Read again closely the [documentation of `GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror). The value it returns only makes sense when you call it _after_ calling a function that is documented to set the error code and only if thet function has failed.

Comment: So is the third value it gives me is wrong? I mean I set it to 0 and then called the function `CreateWindowExA` that seems to re set it to 126, indicating that it is the problem, right? EDIT: GRAMMAR

Comment: If a function documented to set the error code succeeds, the error code is not changed, it could be anything.

Comment: Like I said in my first comment, don't check the error code unless the previous operation actually failed.  You must check what [`CreateWindowExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa) *returns* before checking `GetLastError`. Besides, you need to store the returned value as it's your window handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this (untested code, but you should get the idea).

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
  setDefaultClassParameters(hInstance);

  if (RegisterClassExA(&myWindowsClass) == 0)
  {
    // RegisterClassExA failed => GetErrorCode returns the error code
    printf("RegisterClassExA: ERROR CODE: %i\n", GetLastError()); // Prints 126 Error
    return 1;
  }

  HWND windowHandle = CreateWindowExA(
    WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    "MY CLASS NAME",
    "MY WINDOW TITLE",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL
  );

  if (windowHandle == NULL)
  {
    // CreateWindowExA failed => GetErrorCode returns the error code
    printf("CreateWindowExA ERROR CODE: %i\n", GetLastError()); // Prints 126 Error
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: This indeed improves testing for errors, but it doesn't actually solve the real problem of which is the window not being created / opened.

Comment: Well, that's a totally different question. You should ask a new question such as "CreateWindowEx succeeds, but the window is not shown".